# calling python3 shows error and calling python starts python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to call python3 on my windows 10 machine from cmd.

I've reinstalled Python3.7 to make sure Add to path option was selected, but cannot still call `python3` and make the CMD start Python 3.7.

System variables:

[image]

Whereas `python` in CMD stars Python 2.7:

[image]

I think I need these because when creating a virtualenv, it is created to use Python 2.7:

```
# Windows
python -m venv env
```

**If I search for Python3.7 I can see the exe file and execute it correctly.**

```
C:\Users\OGONZALES\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions are currently in your path, but Python 2.7 is the first, so Windows will start Python 2.7 if you type `python` on the command line.

If you have installed the Python launcher (`py.exe`) you could start Python 3.7 using `py -3.7` and Python 2.7 using `py -2`.

Comment: Perfect, and to create a virtualenv with Python 3.7, one can do: `py -3.7 -m venv myvirtualenv`. But how to set `python3` variable to call `Python 3.7.exe`.

Comment: @OmarGonzales You could create a batch file with the name `python3.bat` and as contents `@py -3 %*` and put it somewhere in your PATH ;-) Note that this wouldn't work from other batch files very well, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm missing something here, because a lot of tutorials I see say use: `python3 manage.py runserver`or other commands...Should I assume they have created a bash file?

Comment: @OmarGonzales, in Linux the Python 3 executable is available under the name `python3` because a lot of other tools/scripts depend on `python` being Python 2. So these examples may be intended for Linux environments. However, in Windows it works a bit differently. And unfortunately the Python launcher is (as far as I know) only available for Windows. So there really are two different mechanisms for executing Python versions in Linux and Windows. I would like this being more standardized and easier, but it isn't... My advice: just read `python3` as `py -3` and you're fine :-)